# ROS/Gazebo/Matlab problem

Tags: ros, matlab, gazebo, ros-kinetic

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I'm trying to create a model in gazebo that use the hokuyo model sensor to generate 3D pointclouds. I have a plugin in gazebo that set the rotational speed of the model (the target speed is set througth a ROS topic). I have also a plugin that publish the laser scan to a ROS node, and I am able to visualize it with rviz. The problem is with Matlab. I am able to conect to the ROS network, I can see all the topics using , I can publish messages to set the speed to a desired one, but im not able to recieve any message from ROS, matlab seems to wait for messages until I finish the fucntion(I use the receive() function). And this happends with every topic.
I use Matlab 2018a, Gazebo 7 and ROS kinect. Does anybody knows If there is some incompatibility issues? The is another method for receiving ROS messages in Matlab?

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/287466/ros/gazebo/matlab-problem/) by [Msan](https://answers.ros.org/users/34492/msan/) on ROS Answers with karma: 3 on 2018-04-04

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) on 2018-04-04**:
May I suggest a title change? Your question is very much about "matlab not receiving any topic data" (or something similar).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Probably a network configuration issue. Make sure to set `ROS_IP` to the appropriate value on *each* involved host. See #q230737.

---

Originally posted by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) with karma: 86574 on 2018-04-04

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Msan](https://answers.ros.org/users/34492/msan/) on 2018-04-04**:
Thank you! Yeah, it was a network problem configuration. I was able to thank to the info on that link.